# How to make an XML tag mandatory with a self-closing tag, using the serialiser?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xml-serialization

I'm working on a C# program and I'm trying to serialise XML.

I have the following tag:

```
using System.Xml.Serialization;
...
[XmlElement("MV")]
public MultiVerse MultiVerse { get; set; }
```

When I don't fill in this value, the tag `<MV>` is not present, but I would like to get a tag `<MV/>` in that case:

Currently I have `<HM><ID>Some_ID</ID></HM>`.
I'd like to have `<HM><ID>Some_ID</ID><MV/></HM>`.

I already tried preceeding the line with `[Required]` but that didn't work, and I think that filling in the `IsNullable` attribute is the good approach.

**Edit1, after some investigation on the internet**
On the internet, there are quite some advises on modifying the `XmlWriter` but in my project, the whole serialisation is done as follows:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    ...
    using (var stream = new StringWriter())
    using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream, settings))
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(base.GetType());
        serializer.Serialize(writer, this, ns);
        return stream.ToString();
    }
    ...
}
```

As you can see, this is so general that I prefer not to do any modifications in here, hence I'm looking for a way to customise the `[XmlElement]` directive.

**Edit2: XmlWriter settings:**
The `XmlWriter settings` look as follows:

```
// Remove Declaration
var settings = new XmlWriterSettings
{
    Indent = false,
    OmitXmlDeclaration = true,
    NewLineHandling = NewLineHandling.None,
    NewLineOnAttributes = false,
};
```

Does anybody have an idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How does the `MultiVerse` class look?

Comment: The `MultiVerse` class is another class, having some properties, some of them also having `[XmlElement()]` directives, but the whole class can be `null`, and that latter is the case I'm interested in.

Comment: In fact, I have a whole bunch of classes, referring to each other. The XML serialiser turns this into a bunch of nested XMLs, which is correct. It happens regularly that one of the objects is `null` and this is then not visible in the resulting XML, which is fine. However, for that one class, the `MultiVerse` class, I would like to see an entry, is possible in the form of a self-closing tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the way I'm currently solving my issue (don't laugh):

```
public override string ToString()
{
    string temp = base.ToString();
    temp = temp.Replace(" p2:nil=\"true\"", "");
    temp = temp.Replace(" xmlns:p2=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"", "");
    temp = temp.Replace("MV />", "MV/>");
    return temp;
}
```

This is hidious! Does anybody have a better solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.isnullable?view=net-6.0 so e.g.

```
[XmlElement("MV", IsNullable=true)]
public MultiVerse MultiVerse { get; set; }
```

would give you, for a null value, a serialization as `<MV xsi:nil="true" />` (or possibly `<MV xsi:nil="true"></MV>` as ensuring the short tag notation is not something the standard writers give you control over but my experience is that .NET usually uses it for empty elements so you might be lucky that your wanted serialization format is the default one .NET outputs).

Comment: I can confirm it's present indeed, but it looks like `<HM><ID>546791133</ID><TC>MS</TC><MV p2:nil="true" xmlns:p2="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" /></HM>`, while I would like `<HM><ID>546791133</ID><TC>MS</TC><MV/></HM>` (the machine I'm sending it to, is very picky), is this possible?

Comment: The built-in, `XSD nil <--> C# null` mapping does represent it this way, so that is what I can suggest based on the existing features in the serializer API and the attributes to customize that. For anything else I think you would need to dig rather deep into the API or post-process the result, I don't remember whether or how you could tune some more settings or whether post-processing is the only way.

Comment: I've added the `XmlWriter` settings, as I found them in my application, but I don't think they are the cause of this strange serialisation results. Nevertheless maybe there is some `XmlWriter` setting which can remove those obsolete entries. Any idea? (Maybe something with `NamespaceHandling`?)

Comment: I don't think in the defined context of XSD based serialization with `XmlSerializer` there is anything strange or obsolete through the use of `xsi:type`, it just serves it purpose to distinguish e.g. an empty `<foo/>` for `public String Foo { get; set; }` representing the empty string value from `<foo xsi:nil="true"/>` representing a null Foo value. As for not having `xsi:nil`, as I said, I am not sure there is a way, the `Serialize` method takes a XmlSerializerNamespaces objects but it doesn't seem to offer a way to suppress/delete a namespace binding for e.g. the xsi namespace.

Comment: So here's the sumarry: the `IsNullable` property gives the possibility to show the tag, but the way it is presented is far from good, because of the presence of namespace related information. So, either, there should be a way to remove all that information, or another way should exist to add this particular tag as self-enclosing in case of `null`.

Comment: I am not sure we get any further, you are making a lot of judgements like `strange`, `obsolete` or `far from good` just because the result that particular API gives doesn't match your wanted or needed input format. I can't see any XML API fail due to an `xsi:nil` attribute on an element to read that element and read out its value but you seem to have a tool that is rather picky. So consider pipelining, like I said, if the result format of the serialization API you use doesn't produce the result your other API can process then use an intermediary processing step filtering out e.g. `xsi:type`.